# Selecting from a IMongoQueryable collection with a Linq Expression throws an error [c# driver 2.2.4]

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Using the mongoDb c# driver 2.2.4, selecting from a IMongoQueryable collection with a Linq Expression throws an error because of my Id field. Here is the code:

```
MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient myClient = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27010");
            var db = myClient.GetDatabase("YOUR_MONGODB_DATABASE");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Man>("Test");
            var queryableCollection = collection.AsQueryable();

            Man obj = new Man() {Id = "Man1_671", Name = "Patrick"};
            collection.InsertOneAsync(obj).Wait();
            // Insertion works fine

            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Man, Man>> func = mec => new Man
            {
                Id = mec.Id,
                Name = mec.Name
            };

            // This line bugs using the 2.2.4 driver and works using the 2.2.1 version
            var listProjection = queryableCollection.Select(func).ToListAsync().Result;
```

Obviously I would have to rename my property to '_id' (tested, it works), but I don't get why it used to work (especially because it is stated that no breaking changes have been introduced). Was I using a bug that had been fixed ? Is it a bug in the driver ? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit 1: exception thrown is : 
Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class MongoDbHierarchicalStoring.Man.

Regards,
Florent

Comment: If it worked at one point and no longer does, then it's certainly a regression. Just because it's stated that no breaking changes were introduced doesn't mean there weren't. Just that none were discovered during testing and we tried not to introduce any in the code. Please file a ticket with repro steps and we'll get it fixed.

Comment: What exception is getting thrown?

Comment: Hi Craig, I just updated the description. The full sample to reproduce the bug is really short, I'll raise a JIRA then. I was just not sure how was handled the Id (or _id) and thought that something may have changed

Comment: Here is the JIRA created, tell me if more info are needed :)
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1719

Regards,
Florent

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around this issue by using a class on top of the real type for the projection purposes:

```
internal class ProductProjection : Product
{ 
    [BsonIgnore]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string _id { set => Id = value; }
}
```

It's then possible to project the aggregate query into this new type and implicitly cast it back:

```
List<Product> results = _collection.Aggregate().Match(queryFilter).Project(
    x => new ProductProjection
    {
        _id = x.Id,
        ....
    }).ToList();
```

The resulting Products contain any custom projections as well as the fully populated Id field.